# Disable activation link email for a specific user group

Tags: craft3, user-groups, activation

I am developing a website which is having two user groups. The users of first user group will have self activation email with account activation link while second user group will be activated by admin after registration. As there is Users Setting for "Verify email addresses?" but we can't do it for specific user group. Is there any solution for it? Please suggest if possible with plugin.

Comment: I'm not aware of an existing plugin that would do this, but are you comfortable writing one?

Comment: Thanks Brad, could you please give me some idea if there is any event or hook we can control it.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, the pseudocode would be something like:

1. Listen for the `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT` event.
2. Check if it's a new user registration.
3. If so, check the user group status.
4. Apply account activation email logic based on #3.